# The Rete Pattern Matching Algorithm no output but no errors as well?

Tags: python, output

I have no errors but don't have outputs either?

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I think the issue is the numberofFacts and probably it is where I am doing something wrong?

```
class weather():
numberOfFacts = 0
count = 0
facts = ''
def __init__(self, FACTS, addFACTS, countFACTS, printFACTS, infer):
   self.FACTS == FACTS
   self.addFACTS == addFACTS
   self.countFACTS == countFACTS
   self.printFACTS == printFACTS
   self.infer == infer

  FACTS.sunIsShining = False;
   FACTS.weatherIsHot = False;
   FACTS.weatherIsCold = False;
   FACTS.wearSunGlasses = False;
   FACTS.summerTime = False;
   FACTS.winterTime = False;
   FACTS.darkClouds = False;
   FACTS.itsRaining = False;
   FACTS.openUmbrella = False;
   FACTS.wearCoat = False;

for fact in f:
     if (FACTS([fact])) ++ 1:
         return count

         for fact in f:

           print("<p>" + fact + "is" + FACT[facts] + "<p>")



   numberOfFacts == countFACTS
     if FACTS.winterTime and FACTS.wearCoat == True: print(FACTS.wearCoat == False)
     if FACTS.weatherIsCold and FACTS.winterTime == True: print(FACTS.summerTime == True)
     if FACTS.itsRaining and FACTS.darkCloud == True: print(FACTS.sunIsShining == False)
     if (FACTS.sunIsShining & FACTS.summerTime) and FACTS.wearSunGlasses == True: print(FACTS.wearSunGlasses == False)
     if FACTS.itsRaining and FACTS.openUmbrella == True: print(FACTS.openUmbrella == False)
     if (FACTS.sunIsShining & FACTS.winterTime) == True: print(FACTS.wearSunGlasses == False, FACTS.darkClouds == False)
     if FACTS.summerTime and FACTS.weatherIsHot == True: print(FACTS.weatherIsHot == False)
     return
```

Comment: It might be an issue with the last part of my code as well as I think i did something wrong with the formatting

Comment: x = "numberofFacts"
x = ""
y = "countFACTS"
y = ""
z = "addFACTS"
z = ""
while( x != y):
             print(addFACTS())
             FACTS.itsRaining == True;
             FACTS.weatherIsCold == True;
             infer()
             print(FACTS)
weather()

Comment: Don't know if something is stuck in an infinite loop hence the no output.

Comment: If it were in an infinite loop, Ctrl-C should stop it. Try running it in the shell. If you see ">>>", you'll know the program finished.

Answer (score 0):

T Von B. = is the assignment operator (the one you want to use) You're using ==, the equality comparison. Instead of assigning to the values in the beginning of your **init**() function, you're comparing them.

EDIT: (1) Why are you using semicolons in Python

(2) You never defined "f" in your for loop.

(3) You're returning something other than None in **init**

Comment: My university core language is c# and I am not really used to Python.
They suggested us to learn it by ourselves and I am kinda a newbie.
Thank you you very much for your help!